# model inversion in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, keras, autoencoders

I am using an Auto-encoder for unsupervised feature learning task. The auto-encoder has a single hidden layer between input and the output layer. The learnt representations are obtained from this hidden layer.

Is it possible to obtain the input from these hidden layer representations ? Note that we are moving in the opposite direction (i.e. from representations to input)

Is there a utility/function available in Keras ?

Comment: Do comment is "model inversion" term I have written in the title of this question is correct

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to obtain the input from these hidden layer representations ? Note that we are moving in the opposite direction (i.e. from representations to input)

You can find an approximation of the input from the latent representation, that is how an auto-encoder is train. The purpose is to find something as close as possible to the input after compressing the information.

> Is there a utility/function available in Keras ?

Check out this article: https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html